# How get the details for given set of URLs using a single Google Analytics API call

Tags: api, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

We are developing an admin Dashboard for our client ecommerce site's with various reports. One of the report we are doing is the organic clicks to the site URLs using Google Analytics API.

Is there any way to get the Google Analytics API result for a given set of URLs? For example: If we pass 15 URLs to the API call, get the Google Analytics details (say organic clicks) for the given 15 URLs only using a SINGLE API call?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the reporting api documentation?

[Run Report](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1beta/properties/runReport) > [Filter Expression](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1beta/FilterExpression) > [Filter](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1beta/FilterExpression#Filter) > [InListFilter](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1beta/FilterExpression#inlistfilter)